# Proving the algorithm gives an optimal solution

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Very often I see solutions to optimization problems that describe an algorithm but do not prove why the algorithm leads to an optimal answer. For example, the following problem showed up in an online competition a couple of days ago:

Let `quantity` be an array of positive integers of size `n`. We would like to generate groups **of different sizes**, each group consisting of unique integers from the interval `[0,n-1]`. What is the maximum number of such groups that can be generated where each used integer `i` does not appear more than `quantity[i]` times across all groups?

There is a very simple algorithm to solve this problem. It seems to me it parallels a constructive algorithm which adds to existing groups integers from a pool. A sample C++ code is below:

```
int maxNumGroups(vector<int>& quantity) {
    
    sort(quantity.begin(), quantity.end());
    int res = 0, pool = 0;
    for(auto& q : quantity){
        pool += q;
        if(pool > res){
            res ++;
            pool -= res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

There are two things that are critical to the algorithm-the sorting and the fact that we only increase the number of groups when a new integer is being considered. With these conditions, the algorithm doesn't prematurely terminate and gives a result. I understand this and the motivation behind it. However, I do not understand why the result is optimal. All of the posts about this problem only write out the algorithm without proving that its optimal.

My questions: is there a technique to prove the algorithm is optimal? Does this problem belong to a category of problems for which it is known how to generate optimal algorithms? Or is this a one off, in which case how would one go about proving it?

EDIT: an attempt at pseudo code of the above

```
sort array quantity 
var numGroups <- 0, pool <- 0
for var q in array quantity:
    pool <- pool + q
    if pool > numGroups:
        numGroups <- numGroups + 1
        pool <- pool - numGroups

return numGroups
```

Comment: I don't know C++ and don't know what that code is doing.  Is there a way  you can describe the algorithm using concise pseudocode?  I don't think you're going to get an answer about all optimization methods.  Are you really asking for an explanation of that one particular algorithm for that one problem?

Comment: My main question is whether this problem falls under a common category and whether there is an associated technique for constructing and proving optimal algorithms. As to whether I'd like to see a proof of the optimality of this specific algorithm (regardless of the answer to my main question), you bet I do! But I'd also understand if this is not the right forum. I have seen now quite a few competition problems that have intuitive algorithms but non-trivial/non-existent proofs of optimality. It is possible they all have something in common I don't know ...

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement or solution, but I suggest you check out the tags for common solution methods, especially [tag:greedy-algorithms], [tag:dynamic-programming].

Comment: What is a "group" in this context? E.g. if `quantity = [3, 5, 1]` what would be the valid "group"s?

Comment: For `quantity` above, an optimal set of groups would be `[0],[0,1],[0,1,2]`

Comment: You need to specify more clearly what constitutes a valid group, so we are able to interpret what problem the algorithm solves, and how and why it's correct. For example, if there were no constraints on the groups (each group was an arbitrary collection of integers), the optimal solution would be having each allowed integer constituting its own, single element group, so you would have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} quantity(i)$ groups.